# Google Maps API Street View panorama displays at wrong angle

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a street view panorama by extracting the information from [Google map link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Vancouver+City+Centre+Dental/@49.2808439,-123.1169053,2a,75y,310h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s3bLDFzZto-EAAAQvOyFhfg!2e0!3e13!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D3bLDFzZto-EAAAQvOyFhfg%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dsearch.TACTILE.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D129%26h%3D106%26yaw%3D310.6578%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i10000!8i5000!4m8!1m2!2m1!1svancouver-city-centre-dental-clinic!3m4!1s0x5486717c6b023f29:0xbe91f088b28dae03!8m2!3d49.2808671!4d-123.1169685).

```
    $(function () {

    // Information extacted from url 
    // @49.2808439,-123.1169053,2a,75y,310h,90t

    var params = {
        lat: 49.2808439,
        lng: -123.1169053,
        heading: 310,
        pitch: 0,
        zoom: 1,
        panoId: 'F:3bLDFzZto-EAAAQvOyFhfg'
    };

    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map'), {
        position: { lat: params.lat, lng: params.lng },
        zoom: params.zoom,
        pov: { heading: params.heading, pitch: params.pitch },
        addressControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        }

    });

});
```

**Google map shows following view.**

[image]

**My code shows different map view.**

[image]

The window size is also same, I am not able to identify the issue in my code. Please help. Thanks

Comment: The point of view of the panorama is a little better when you specify the panorama ID in the StreetViewPanoramaOptions like this:
`var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map'), {
    pano: '3bLDFzZto-EAAAQvOyFhfg'
  });`
However, the camera still does not face the right direction...

Comment: How are you extracting the heading (310)? That seems to be wrong.

Comment: I have extracted from URL @49.2808439,-123.1169053,2a,75y,310h,90t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're not using the `pano` property of the `StreetViewPanorama` and you got a different pano ID as well. Just as was commented already.

Just add the `pano` prop, but the correct one (`3bLDFzZto-EAAAQvOyFhfg`) like this:

```
var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
     document.getElementById('pano'), {
       pano: params.panoId, // this one
       zoom: params.zoom,
       pov: { heading: params.heading, pitch: params.pitch },
       addressControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        }
     });
```

See the working code below.

Or this [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/hux6930L/)

Note: use your own API key

```js
 var params = {
   lat: 49.2808439,
   lng: -123.1169053,
   heading: 310,
   pitch: 0,
   zoom: 1,
   panoId: '3bLDFzZto-EAAAQvOyFhfg'
 };

 function initialize() {
   var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
     document.getElementById('pano'), {
       pano: params.panoId,
       zoom: params.zoom,
       pov: { heading: params.heading, pitch: params.pitch },
       addressControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        }
     });
 }
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#pano {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="pano"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initialize">
</script>
```